# How can a hacker put a file on my server root (apache, php, 1and1)

Tags: php, apache, security

I have a site hosted on 1and1 and a couple of weeks ago I noticed a hacker had put a .php file on the server that when viewed in a browser exposed my DB schema, DB connection strings, FTP account (for file uploads using a form), etc, etc. Naturally I panicked and I wiped the server and reuploaded my files. Fortunatley I encrypt passwords using MD5 and I don't store things like credit card details, etc, etc.

Now I checked my files and with all user input I use a clean function (htmlentities, sql_real_escape_string, etc, etc) that strips the input of any XSS or SQL injection. I have also made sure that the session key gets re-engineered when a user status changes (like they log into their account) to prevent session hijacking, my folder permissions are set to 755 and file permission are 644.

Has anyone got any idea how this could have happened? Or if I'm missing something

Comment: most of  precautions you took looks like made things worse

Comment: for example in sake of not having 777 on directories, you're using ftp to save files on the same host, which is ridiculous. also, mixing "htmlentities, sql_real_escape_string, etc, etc" not in place and without understanding may cause opposite effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most usual cause is trojan horse that steal passwords from the FTP client on the developer's PC.

Comment: Yep, that happened to a colleague of mine.

Comment: I experienced this problem in my previous work. The main reason was IE in computer with saved FTP passwords.

Comment: My laptop did have trojans on it! Not 100% this is the reason but it's too close for comfort - thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is through an upload script of some kind, for example I have see poorly protected image upload scripts allow this behaviour. I've actually seen this once in a script that resized images on the fly but used GET variables for the location of the image to resize. Its also worth checking any usages of `exec()` or `system()` for possible weaknesses. If its possible to access your server via SSH you could also check all commands run recently using the command `history`

Comment: I do have an image upload form but that's only available to Admin users and not the general public?

Comment: Well, I check if they have an admin session (admin must log in with username & pass), if they don't they can't access the page

Comment: The SSH thing may be a clue as I've been using putty recently so I can access my crontab